# how to filter entity type in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, entity

I got an array of two items. I want to filter the array and return the item only if fromType matches EntityType.producerSite .

```
var transferlist = [Transfer($id: 62c57c7810a57a59fe1e, fromType: EntityType.producerSite, fromId: 629f5ffd2b6386c83057, toType: null, timestamp: 2022-07-06 13:13:44.016), Transfer($id: 62c57c7810a57a59fe1e, fromType: EntityType.bin, fromId: 629f5ffd2b6386c83057, toType: null, timestamp: 2022-07-06 13:13:44.016)]
```

I try this but it didn't work

```
var newTransferList = []

     for (var transfer in transferlist) {
       if (transfer.fromType == "EntityType.producerSite") {
          newTransferList.add(transfer)
       } 
     }
```

Comment: can you add Transfer class too?

Comment: To make your code work, just remove the double quotes (")
(https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `where`, your main issue is you put `EntityType.producerSite` inside `" "` :

```
var result = transferlist.where((element) => element.fromType == EntityType.producerSite).toList();
```

or if you want it in for loop form:

```
for (var transfer in transferlist) {
   if (transfer.fromType == EntityType.producerSite) {
          newTransferList.add(transfer)
    } 
}
```